# Preserving SQLite db data on App Update/Reinstall Rollout Xamarin

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, database-backups

I have Xamarin.Forms shared project that I am testing on Android phone currently.

The sqlite db is stored in `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` as of now.

I want to make sure that user input data stored in db is preserved:

## 1 upon each next upgrade I am planning for an app, as well as

## 2 In additional situation where user removes his app totally and makes a fresh install

(I guess these are two totally different situations, but I might be wrong)

I would like to know whether an update of an App via Google Play Store Update will overwrite db file too, therefore all data be lost? Or will the data be preserved?

What would be the option if a user wanted to preserve his/her data even after an app Uninstall/Reinstall?

In second case, I am considering manual/automatic backup of SpecialFolder.Personal db version in use and storing it as a separate file outside of the package using External_STORAGE permissions.

Then the user will be able to Import data from external db file copy into the one that comes in the package.

Also, how should the Import look like?
Can I simply replace the file with external one?

Any advice on this topic will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An update from Google Play will not overwrite the db file
2. If a user uninstalls the application, he will want to delete everything related with the application. So my best solution is to have a synchronize method within your API so that, when the user installs again the application, it will fill the local DB with the requested data.

Comment: brilliant news. I hoped that data will not be affected by app update. For second case then, I will put a Backup/Restore button within the app that will make a backup to external storage and restore file if user makes a fresh install.